# Modify a singleton dependency on each module import

Tags: angular

I have a use case in my application:

There is an `ApiModule`, there are 2 services in it, both are scoped to the module itself. One is `ApiRouteService` and the other one is `ApiRouteLoaderService`. Now for the purpose:

1. `ApiRouteService`: It maintains a cache of api routes (route method, name, url etc) and returns an api route object identified by name when asked for it.
2. `ApiRouteLoaderService`: It just loads the raw api routes and parses them to be used by `ApiRouteService`.

The modules in my application are lazy loaded. Now here's the scenario:

When the `AuthModule` is lazy loaded. It will import the `ApiModule.forFeature(AuthApiRoutes)`. The `forFeature` method looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    providers: [ApiRouteService, ApiRouteLoaderService],
})
export class ApiModule {
    public static forFeature(apiRoutes: Array<IRawApiRoute>): ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: ApiModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ApiRouteService,
                    useFactory: (apiRouteLoaderService: ApiRouteLoaderService, apiRouteService: ApiRouteService) => {
                        const parsedApiRoutes = apiRouteLoaderService.loadRoutes(apiRoutes);

                        // Now I need the singleton instance of ApiRouteService, so I can call
                        // apiRouteService.registerRoutes(parsedApiRoutes); and it will add the routes in
                        // apiRouteService instance along others.

                        // But I can't call the above, because I need the initial instance of ApiRouteService
                        // Also note that this function will be called only once when ApiModule is loaded
                        // in any module
                    },
                    deps: [ApiRouteLoaderService, ApiRouteService /* <-- This ApiRouteService causes circular loop */],
                },
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

How I can achieve this? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you want to do, but it looks like you just need to call `apiRouteLoaderService.loadRoutes` and `apiRouteService.registerRoutes` on module initialization. I don't think you actually want to provide another instance of the `ApiRouteService` do you? If that is the case I would just provide the `apiRoutes`, inject the dependencies and call the methods like this:

```js
export const ROUTES = new InjectionToken<Array<IRawApiRoute>>('routes');

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    providers: [ApiRouteService, ApiRouteLoaderService],
})
export class ApiModule {
    constructor(
        private apiRouteService: ApiRouteService,
        private apiRouteLoaderService: ApiRouteLoaderService,
        @Inject(ROUTES) @Self() @Optional() private routes?: Array<IRawApiRoute>
    ) {
        if(routes) {
            const parsedApiRoutes = this.apiRouteLoaderService.loadRoutes(routes);
            this.apiRouteService.registerRoutes(parsedApiRoutes);
        }
    }

    public static forFeature(apiRoutes: Array<IRawApiRoute>): ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: ApiModule,
            providers: [{
                provide: ROUTES,
                useValue: apiRoutes,
            }],
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor, you are checking, whether the routes have been injected before. Am I right? If that's the case. What will happen if I import the ApiModule in another module, say CustomerModule and try to register the routes of CustomerModule? What I want is: **If any module imports the `ApiModule.forFeature(routes)`, then add that module's routes in the singleton instance of ApiRouteService, so that when I use ApiRouteService in that module, I shoudl be able to get the routes from the service instance**

Thank you for your response and time and I'm sorry if I'm still unable to explain :(

Comment: The check for the routes is there, because if you import the `ApiModule` without specifying `.forFeature` no routes are available and it would error. If you import the module multiple times it should add the routes correctly.

Comment: Hmm... That worked beautifully <3. Now here's the thing that I understood. If I imported a module in three other modules, then the constructor of the imported module will be called three times. But what about ROUTES injection token. When I import the module for the first time, the injection token gets registered against the provided api routes. When I import the module for the second time, shouldn't the ROUTES injection token gets resolved to the api routes that were provided in the first module import?

Comment: This works because angular builds a tree of injectors. At the root there is the root injector. Every module creates a new injector under the parent injector. While resolving dependencies angular looks first in the current injector and if not found goes up the tree from there. The `@Self` annotation tells angular to only look for dependencies in the current injector and every module has their own instance of the `ROUTES` dependency. You can learn about this in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

Comment: Ahh.. Now I get it. Thank you for your response and time :) I learned something new today.